# Are browsers swapping video source on resize or fullscreen?

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Given a video that is hosted in different sizes to optimize for different devices, as in [MDN’s example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#using_the_media_attribute_with_video):

```
<video controls>
  <source src="foo-large.webm" media="(min-width: 800px)">
  <source src="foo.webm">
  I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML video.
</video>
```

I’m wondering whether browsers are switching from one source to the other when the viewport gets resized?

I guess technically they could, one would expect that in most cases the video contents and durations are the same, and most modern containers allow for streaming and random access if I’m not mistaken.

Do they?

Comment: The code in this question was [taken from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source#using_the_media_attribute_with_video). So, what did you find when you searched for an answer, or tested this yourself?

Comment: As I’m currently lacking two video files, I didn’t test yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<source>` tag allows browsers to pick the best video source for the user's device, ensuring an optimal viewing experience. Initially, the browser selects a video based on screen size, but it won't switch qualities if the screen size changes during playback to avoid playback issues.

It even selects the source when initialised, resizing the browser window won’t change the source even before playback, at least in Chrome and Firefox.

For dynamic quality adjustments, technologies like [MPEG-DASH (Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) or [HLS (HTTP Live Streaming)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) are recommended, as they adapt to changing conditions without needing a video reload.

They provide several segments in different qualities inside one container, so only a single source needs to be provided.

> While MPEG-DASH isn't directly supported in HTML5, there are JavaScript implementations of MPEG-DASH which allow using MPEG-DASH in web browsers using the HTML5 Media Source Extensions (MSE).

[MDN provides guidance on how to set up DASH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video).

In the example you've provided, the browser will choose which `<source>` to use when the video is initially loaded based on the current viewport width. If the viewport width is 800 pixels or wider, the browser will choose foo-large.webm; otherwise, it will fall back to foo.webm.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Could you provide more details for the technologies that allow for dynamic quality adjustments?

Comment: @Andy You're now asking a new question. Please do _not_ change your question to add this new question, but ask an actual new question. If you're happy with the answer you can show that by upvoting it. If this does answer your question satisfactory you can tick it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I’m not changing my question, but sources are always welcome in answers. In this case, it would be highly pertinent to know whether browsers support DASH or HLS.

Comment: Would you have more insights into how browsers can pick a video source based on network conditions? I don’t find any proof of that.

Comment: @Andy, browsers don't pick a video source based on network conditions. In the case of HLS it is the playlist file (M3U8 format) that will specify which specific files to play from a list of their related/target network speeds. An app (or media player) is supposed to check the users network speed and then load the "nearest" video file for that speed.

Comment: Thx. That’s what I thought, so I removed the statement from this answer.